# Parseerror in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I don't know where the error is coming from? I changed the compiler from 0.8.17 to 0.8.0 but the constrcutor function keeps showing this error.
"ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum/constant/function/error definition." on the constructor function

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0; 
contract MedicalKeyEncapsulation {
    address  public Doctor;
    address  public Patient;
    bytes32 private encapA;  
    bytes32 private encapB; 
}

    struct Patientdata{
        string pName;
        uint256 PID;
        uint256 Date;
        string disesaseinfo;
    }

     struct DocRecord{
        string DocName;
        uint256 DID;
        uint256 Date;
        string specialiazation;
        bytes32 hcn_hash;
    }

   

    constructor (address _Patientdata, address _DoctorRecord) public {
    Patient = msg.sender;
    Doctor =_Doctor;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 curly bracket after your variables declaration that ends your contract.
Fixed below

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0; 
contract MedicalKeyEncapsulation {
    address  public Doctor;
    address  public Patient;
    bytes32 private encapA;  
    bytes32 private encapB; 


    struct Patientdata{
        string pName;
        uint256 PID;
        uint256 Date;
        string disesaseinfo;
    }

     struct DocRecord{
        string DocName;
        uint256 DID;
        uint256 Date;
        string specialiazation;
        bytes32 hcn_hash;
    }

   

    constructor (address _Patientdata, address _DoctorRecord) public {
    Patient = msg.sender;
    Doctor =_Doctor;
   }
}
```